# PyTest: Use results from previous test to parametrize next tests

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

I'm using PyTest and Selenium to test all options listed in a dropdown menu on a website. I want to navigate to that page, grab all the available options in the dropdown, and then use parametrize to create new sub-tests to click each option and test UI elements. It looks like this:

```
class TestOptions:

    dropdown_options = []

    def test_login(self):
        ...

    def test_navigate_to_page(self):
        ...

    def test_grab_all_options(self):
        self.dropdown_options = get_all_dropdown_option_names()
        # test that all option names follow a criteria
        ...

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("option", dropdown_options)
    def test_each_option(self, option):
        find_option_by_name(option).click()
        # tests
        ...
```

The problem is that I believe parametrize is set before any tests begin so it sees dropdown_options as an empty list. Is there a work-around so I can dynamically populate that list?

Comment: You have to fill the parameter at load time, before it is used in the decorator, e.g. before the test, something like `dropdown_options = get_all_dropdown_option_names()` instead of `dropdown_options = []` in the class definition. It is not possible to do it the way you try to. Or you could iterate over the options in the test itself, without parametrization.

Comment: Is there a way to generate separate tests for these options without parametrization?

Comment: There are hooks that you could use to create or parametrize tests. The problem is that these are executed before test execution, so you won't have the information that is generated by that other test.