# pytest - parametrize a test with parameters that are only calculated on runtime

Tags: python, pytest

I am trying to parametrize a test with a list of params that i am fetching from a database.
In order to set these params i also need to use the command line arguments and some of my fixture.

I initiate a global variable in pytest_configure, and changing it in my session_init.
However, when parametrizing, the global variable is still empty - which means the parametrizing happens before session_init.

Is there any way to perform this action before parametrizing? (note that i need my fixtures + request fixture)

Comment: The parameters are in a decorator, meaning they are read at load time - so they cannot depend on the test class or fixtures. See also this recent [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62411938/pytest-use-results-from-previous-test-to-parametrize-next-tests).

Comment: That being said, you can generate the parameters in the hook `pytest_generate_tests` manually - I'm not sure if this also too late for your use case, though.

Comment: That is happening before test execution also, is there any way to parametrize tests after test execution? 
The reason is having test per parameter, maybe there is another way to do that.

Comment: Not that I know of. I think the only way to execute the tests in your case is to iterate over the parameters in the test itself - which does not create separate tests for each parameter, of course.